# Android LocationRequest: get a callback when request expires

Tags: android, android-location

im wonder how to catch event or what ever when my LocationReqest expired, heres code then i call it

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setExpirationDuration(500);
    mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1); 
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
```

now i need to get know that my LocationRequest was break, ty for help :)

edit

i thought i could catch it in

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
//something is here
}
```

but its doesnt work :(

edit2

i partial solved it by adding handler that check after N+500ms if location was set, im still wonder if i can do it without handler

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setExpirationTime%28long%29) does not speak about any callback in this case, I guess you do have to use a timer to trigger an event if your request expires without any location update.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll have to handle it yourself. Post a Runnable with a delay immediately after requestLocationUpdates like this:

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setExpirationDuration(500);
mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1); 
mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
mHandler.postDelayed(mExpiredRunnable, 500);
```

Here's the Runnable:

```
private final Runnable mExpiredRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showUnableToObtainLocation();
    }
};
```

The showUnableToObtainLocation method would have whatever logic you wanted to execute when a location fix could not be obtained.

In the normal case where you actually do get a location fix you put code in onLocationChanged to cancel the Runnable:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mExpiredRunnable);
```

You would also want this same code in your onPause method as well in case the Activity/Fragment is backgrounded before a location fix OR the request expires.

Comment: I even tried a lot and i think this is only way out left. I tried using setMaxWaitTime method in LocationRequest but even that too does not give a callback when wait time is over.