# Android Location Request expiration callback

Tags: android

So I have set up my locationRequest as follows:

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setExpirationDuration(MAX_DURATION_SEC);
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,locationRequest, this);
```

It works great, but I would like my app to perform a certain action if a location has not been acquired by the time the request expires. I figured the onConnectionSuspended() callback would do the trick, but that doesnt seem to the the case.

How would I go about getting some sort of callback when the request expires?

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you find any solution for the above problem?

Comment: Nope. Gave it up and redesigned that part of the app.

Comment: How did you solve this problem, can you pleas give a short description about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android LocationRequest: get a callback when request expires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414792/android-locationrequest-get-a-callback-when-request-expires)